tabularx X columns breaking depending on table width
I need a table with many (31) columns of equal width, on a landscape page with tight margins. My first thought was to reach for tabularx and its X columns.
Unfortunately, there appears to be an upper limit on the number of X columns, above which the table layout breaks. What's more, this appears to be dependent on the width of the table.
Here's an MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
        Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
        Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{.9\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
        Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla&bla&Bla
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}

This produces

I have two -- well, three -- questions.

(Optional) Why does this happen?
How can I avoid it when using tabularx?
Since I'm not hung up on tabularx in this specific case, are there alternatives for designing a table with many columns of equal width in LaTeX?

